# Dynamically add/remove option from Kendo DrownDownList with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropDownList like this

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list="container.KilometerAllowanceDropDown" k-options="KilometerAllowanceOptions" ng-change="kilometerAllowanceChanged()" class="fill-width" id="KilometerAllowance" ng-model="DriveReport.KilometerAllowance">
    <option value="Calculated">A</option>
    <option value="Read">B</option>
    <option value="CalculatedWithoutExtraDistance">C</option>
</select>
```

I wish to remove the third `option` based on a bool in my controller. The bool will get evaluated when the page loads, and will not change after that.

I tried adding a `ng-disable` or a `ng-show` to the third `option` tag, and binding that to the bool, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You could achieve that by using a `DataSource`. Just use a array of values, and `add`/`remove` values as needed.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, I ended up using the `ng-options` tag in my `select` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the `ng-options` tag in the `select` tag. My view:

```
ng-options="option.value as option.key for option in kilometerOptions"
```

The kilometerOptions is an array of objects like the former options. My controller:

```
    var kilometeroptions = new Array();
    kilometeroptions.push({ value: "Calculated", key: "A" });
    kilometeroptions.push({ value: "Read", key: "B" });
    if (!alternativeCalculation) {
        kilometeroptions.push({ value: "CalculatedWithoutExtraDistance", key: "C" });
    }
    $scope.kilometerOptions = kilometeroptions;
```

alternativeCalculation is the bool that will decide if option C will be included.